# How do I automatically generate front matter for my jekyll blog posts?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

1. I have a website that has a jekyll-powered blog in it. It has some other static files on the website too. The website is hosted on **Github pages**.
2. My question is: How do I make sure that the title and category is listed in every jekyll post automatically? I don't intend to make a second category so I am lumping all the posts in the 'blog' category. I would like the title of the url to be the same as the url of the post.

   ```
   ---
   title: The great wall of China
   category: blog
   ---
   ```
3. I don't want to keep writing the above in every single post. So I need to write some code in **_config.yml**, but my code is wrong. Am really stuck here!!

   ```
   markdown: kramdown
   exclude: [README.md]
   permalink: /work/:title

   prose:
     rooturl: '_posts/'
     siteurl: 'http://prose.github.io/starter/'
     relativeLinks: 'http://prose.github.io/starter/links.jsonp'
     media: 'media'

     ignore:
       - index.md
       - _config.yml
       - /_data
       - /_includes

     metadata:
       _posts:
         - name: "title"
           field:
             element: "text"
             label: "title"
         - name: "category"
           field:
             element: "hidden"
             value: "entries"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

### How do I make sure that the title and category is listed in every jekyll post automatically?

You can change the permalink to `/blog/my-post/`, and remove the category from the individual posts. Just add `permalink: /blog/:title/` to your 'config.yml' file. Then, add the category name in plain text to the template if you want/need it.

---

### I don't want to keep writing the [front matter] in every single post.

You will need to write the title in the front matter anyway, as it is different for each post. IMHO adding defaults to the `_config.yml` is not really a win here...